# Detecting UseChromeNetworking from JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome-frame

Is it possible to use JavaScript to detect whether Google Chrome Frame is using its own networking stack rather than Internet Explorer’s? Alternatively, is there any way in HTML or JavaScript to force use of Chrome Frame’s own networking code without having to set UseChromeNetworking in the Windows Registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this problem by writing a server-side script that echoed the UserAgent string back to my JavaScript code. When UseChromeNetworking is not set, the UserAgent string contains the string “chromeframe”.